# SQl query with inner join

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I am new to sql.I am working with SQL queries where i have two tables
Table 1 have this data:

```
Student_id        Name      Surname         Department
```

Table 2   have this data:

```
Exam_id          Exam        Date
```

My question what column can i add to tables to join these tables together and get desired data from example : a student who have exam in physics.

Comment: Can you add which database you are using, SQL is just query language

Comment: This is *data modellng*, not SQL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: This isn't a programming question, since you have no evidence of any SQL code or what RDBMS/dialect it's needed for; and anyway, I find it very hard to believe that you would not find an answer to (many, more specific versions of) the same question on SO or other SE sites if you had tried to searched, not to mention in a textbook or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third table in which you can add `Student_Id` And `Exam_Id`. This table will act as a bridge table between above two tables.

Since this case is for many to many relationships.

**For example:**

A student can have more than one exam on different dates and an exam can be given by different students.

[image: Relationship]

So your database diagram will look like the above one if you want to make a relationship between `Student` and `Exam`.

Take a simple example:

**STUDENT**

```
Student_Id  Name  SurName   Department
 1           ABC    XYZ      Science
 2           DEF    YXZ      Science
```

**EXAM**

```
Exam_Id   Exam       Date
 1        Physics    12-4-2018
 2        Chemistry  15-4-2018
 3        Biology    18-4-2018
 4        Maths      20-4-2018
```

Now how will you make a relationship between these two tables?
The answer is you have to create one bridge table (as said earlier) like this

**Student_Exam_link**

```
Id  Student_ID  Exam_Id
1       1         1
2       2         1
3       1         2
4       2         2
5       1         3
6       2         4
```

In above table 1st row says: `Student with id 1 ie. ABC has the exam of id 1 i.e. Physics`

similarly, 2nd row says: `Student with id 2 ie. DEF has also the exam of id 1 i.e. Physics`

and so on.

Now, How can you join these tables?

Use `Join` on these three tables together to get the desired results.For Example:
Join `Student` table with `Student_Exam_link` table on student_id and then join the resulting table with `Exam` table On exam_id.

For more info follow the below link :

> https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html

Comment: #Nishant -can you give me an example, cause i am new. After i create the third tables what query to use to get desired data

Comment: Please Go to the link given if you find it difficult to understand I will explain you in more detail.

Comment: Could you please explain me more in detail, cause i just started to learn in this are. If you dont mind

Answer (score 0):

```
One Student can takes Many Exams and also Many Students can take One Exam.
```

Thus it results in Many-to-Many relationship. Better approach would be introduce a new mapping table `Student Exam Mapping table` with columns

```
id   Exam_id    Student_id
```